# Why did my professor write down the Einstein field equations like this?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light, cosmological-constant, absolute-units

Ok, so I was taking an online course where the professor wrote down the Einstein field equations like this

$$R_{\mu \nu }-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu }R = 8\pi G\: T_{\mu \nu }.$$

But I saw it most commonly written as

$$R_{\mu \nu }-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu }R\:  + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu } = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}\: T_{\mu \nu }.$$

It seems to me that these two variations are not the same. Are they or not? Then, what reasons would lambda be left out/incorporated along with $c^4$ as the denominator on the right-hand side?

Comment: Can you please link the online course website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra term in the field equations, $\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ is often written with a capital lambda, i.e. $\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$. $\Lambda$ is the [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#:%7E:text=In%20cosmology%2C%20the%20cosmological%20constant,of%20dark%20energy%20and%20quintessence.).

The second part of your questions asks why the speed of light is apparently being omitted, this is because we are using [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) in which $c=1$ and is also dimensionless. Geometrized units (discussed in the Wikipedia link) is frequently used in general relativity.

Comment: I see, but when would you place lambda in the expression?

Comment: @Tachyon When you don’t want to treat the cosmological constant as being zero.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, that makes sense and all, but when would you want it not be zero? In which context or situation?

Comment: In general, it should be there, because the constant *isn’t* zero based on observational data. Sometimes we take it to be zero because it doesn’t matter in the early universe. It only plays a major role in the late universe.

Comment: @Tachyon The motivation for a non-vanishing cosmological constant is discussed in the first few paragraphs of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @G.Smith Okay, I see. But if it is common is write it and it is based on observational data, then why would my professor omit it from the equation?

Comment: I can’t read your professor’s mind. Maybe they are presenting the field equations in a historical way. Einstein originally didn’t have the cosmological constant term. Your professor will probably get around to adding it at some point, since it is now part of standard cosmology.

Comment: @G.Smith Ok, so one last question then: which equation is more correct and which should be preferred over the other? With or without lambda? Does it matter? Also, I have read the wiki on it and it doesn't say which one is more "correct".

Comment: The lambda term appear in a simmilar manner as integration constants do

Comment: @Tachyon The one with lambda is more correct, in my opinion.

Comment: @Tachyon But some people like to move the lambda term to the right-hand side of the equation and treat it as if it is part of the energy-momentum tensor, as in “dark energy”. This could be what your prof prefers.

Comment: @Tachyon Lambda term is also irrelevant if you are investigating field around the star or black hole or something like that. It is just too small to play significant role in such a small distances. So the discussion of lambda might be postponed until you start cosmology. My guess would be that this is the reason why your professor did not include it yet.